# Python: Sockets: can't connect over internet, only works on localhost

Tags: python, sockets, connection, internet-connection

I am experimenting with Python's Sockets.  I am just trying to get a 'web chat' window to work for now.  It works on localhost but not over the internet.  I have tried port forwarding through my router, still not working.  I need some assistance.

Server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()#s = server (good practice)

print("Socket Created")
hostname=socket.gethostname()
localip=socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print(localip)
Port=input("Enter Port Number here: ")

s.bind(("0.0.0.0",int(Port))) #bind the server ip, in this case local host, (()) are used because .bind only takes 1 arguments so putting 2 things in as 1 is acceptable

s.listen(6)

print("Waiting for connections")

while True: #holds open window
    c,addr=s.accept() #c is the client socket, addr is address of the clien
    print("Connected with ",addr)
    while True:    
        incoming=c.recv(1024).decode()
        if incoming=="x":
            c.close()
            quit()
        else:
            print(incoming)
            inpt=input("Retort Here: ")
            c.send(bytes(inpt,"utf-8"))
```

Client:

```
    import socket

c = socket.socket() #c = client (good practice)

print("Socket Created.  Looking for server.")

while True:
    try:
        IPAddr=input("IP Address: ")

        Port=input("\nPort: ")

        c.connect((IPAddr,int(Port)))

        print("Connection established, type x to quit")

        incoming=0
        while incoming!="x":

            inpt=input("Send Message here: ")

            c.send(bytes(inpt,'utf-8'))

            incoming=c.recv(1024).decode()

            print(incoming)

        c.close()
        quit()
    except:
        print("oops, try again")
```

Comment: With "over the internet" you mean two devices in the same network?

Comment: *"I have tried port forwarding through my router, still not working."* - this description is too unspecific. What exactly means "not working" - please provide exact errors. Also how is the port forwarding done and where are client and server are located. If they are located in the same network behind the router but you just try to access the server by the external IP the problem might be caused by the router not supporting NAT loopback.

Comment: Make sure your firewall isn't blocking it.

Comment: No, we are on different networks, it works between machines on localhost.

"not working" means the client won't be able to connect, it will pause for minute to connect, nothing occurs, then the except catches the issue (it just prevents CTD).

Port forwarding was done through "Windows Defender Firewall", adding in an exception to the port we desire for inbound and outbound.  I have also set up an open port in my router's settings by going to the Advanced settings and NAT and adding a rule to allow access to the desired port.

The purpose of this is so I can communicate with my friends.